# Duplicate AssemblyTitle Attribute when using MCImageManager

Tags: c#, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I just bought a pack of MCImageManager an hour ago and set i up as follows:-

1. Unpack the imagemanager and copy it to the tinymce plugins directory (tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager).
2. Copy the dll files from imagemanager/bin to your sites root bin for example c:/inetpub/wwwroot/bin
3. Add imagemanager to the TinyMCE init plugins option.
4. Add insertimage to the list of buttons in the TinyMCE init options.

Refrenced the assemblies.

Now when i buld the project i get 20 errors and all saying Duplicate 'AssemblyTitle' Attribute.

How can I resolve this error?

I think this error is most probably because i have refreced a MoxieCode.ISharpCode....dll
And I also have it in my application.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this appears to be cross posted under the name abhishekjirawla here:  [ASP.NET c# forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1862882.aspx/1?Duplicate+AssemblyTitle+Attribute+when+using+MCImageManager); if you cross post, you should say so. see the replies at forums.asp.net